# What are the limitations of what can be assigned as a Pushpin's Name property?

Tags: c#, bing-maps, pushpin

As the Name property is a string, I reckon you could assign any string value to it; on the other hand, doing this programmatically:

```
Pushpin rupertTPupkin@att.net = new Pushpin();
```

...doesn't work, due to the @ symbol, so ... what are the limitations of what can be assigned to a Pushpin's Name property?

Comment: You're declaring a variable, not setting a name property...

Comment: Yes, but isn't the variable name the object's name property? If not, then my question is: what IS the name you give the object - its ID?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Pushpin object, but I would imagine you would do something like this `Pushpin pin = new Pushpin(); pin.Name = "rupertTPupkin@att.net";`

Comment: Right; but that's my question - would such a string be acceptable. It's not doing it as I show, so that's why I wonder...

Comment: _but isn't the variable name the object's name property?_ no - as Schmiddty pointed out, you are creating and assigning a new variable. What if I were then to write `Pushpin ohNo = rupertTPupkin@att.net;`, what would the name be? See _Public Properties_ > _Name_ under http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.pushpin_members.aspx, quote: _Gets or sets the identifying name of the element. The name provides a reference so that code-behind, such as event handler code, can refer to a markup element after it is constructed during processing by a XAML processor._

Comment: My real question is, then: can a variable name have an "@" symbol in it? It seems not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable name can not have the "@" symbol in it. In C# a variable name can be any alphanumeric value as long as the first character is not a number. You can also use underscores. No other characters can be used in a variable name. The "@" has a special meaning when it comes to variables in c# and can be placed as a prefix to the variable name. When this is done the "@" symbol enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim identifier